# iframe giving cross origin error with youtube src

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, youtube-iframe-api

I have an Reactjs nextjs app setup with an iframe src here:

```
          <iframe
            width="100%"
            height="100%"
            src={"https://www.youtube.com/embed/c0-hvjV2A5Y"}
            title="YouTube video player"
            frameBorder="0"
            allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
            allowFullScreen
          />
```

however when i use multiple iframes to load multiple videos on one page I'm am getting repeated errors like this:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://play.google.com/log?format=json&hasfast=true&authuser=0. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).
```

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: SO they do not let you use an iframe. Nothing you can do to get around that. Use their api.

Comment: you have to register your app. they give you an api key. everytime you make request with the given api key, your app will be recognized and allowed

Comment: where should i be registering the app I cannot find a link on https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Comment: have u fixed it,im facing same issue